# jQuery:: AJAX is not return any callback

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, callback

For some reason I'm not getting the callback from `post.php`

Here is my `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_upload">
<button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
</form>

<div id=callbackEcho></div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$("button").on("click",uploading);

function uploading(e)
{

    e.preventDefault();
    var postData=new FormData($("form")[0]);

    $.ajax
    (
        {
            type:'POST',
            url:"post.php",
            data:postData,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#callbackEcho").html('success : '+data);
            },
            fail:function(data)
            {
                $("#callbackEcho").html('fail : '+data);
            },
            done:function(data)
            {
                $("#callbackEcho").html('done : '+data);
            }
        }
    );

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and for testing only this is my `post.php`:

```
<?php

echo 'I\'m a callback!';
exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ajax call to the following

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:"post.php",
  data:postData,
  contentType:false,
  processData:false,
  success:function(data) {
    $("#callbackEcho").html('success : '+data);
  },
  error:function(data) {
    $("#callbackEcho").html('fail : '+data);
  },
  complete: function(data) {
    $("#callbackEcho").html('done : '+data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Man! Working perfectly!